# submitting data via form to server c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So I have a form that gathers some data

I am using the jQuery ui lib to have the  form. It is built from this html:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="form name">
<form>
<fieldset>
<label for="opis_naziv">Kratak opis: </label>
<input type="text" name="opis" id="opis_naziv" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /><br />
<div id='jqxDDHitnost'></div>
<label for="opis_sadrzaj">Puni opis: </label><br />
<textarea  cols="76" name="opis_sadrzaj" id="opis_sadrzaj" rows="10" class="textarea ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" ></textarea><br />
<label for="dodatak">Dodaj datoteku (do 4MB): </label>
<input type="file" name="dodatak" id="dodatak" value="" class="file ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /><br />
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

and this javascript to init it:

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 600,
                width: 700,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Kreiraj": function () {
                       //code needed
                    },
                    "Odustani": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
```

I have c# code server side and I would like to know how to gather all data in the form and send it to the server.

The thing that is problematic is the file upload. The rest I have an idea of how to send but not sure about the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i used the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) and that solved all my problems. and thank you Shant for telling me about the `runat="server"` option.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I will suggest that on the button click callback function, you can perform following steps to send data to server:

1. Prepare an XML string having name-value / id-value pair of your form
   controls (eg "<field id='opis_naziv' value=" +
   $('#opis_naziv').val() + "/>").
2. Store the XML string in a hidden control (textbox, etc.) with
       runat="server" attribute
3. Trigger click of button control with runat="server" attribute which will pass the control to server click event of the button where you can access the XML string from above control, parse it and use the values.

I will personally recommend calling a WebMethod on click of your button to perform server side operation.

Comment: fair enough, but how do i get the file selected in the file input?

Comment: So you need the code to upload the file? Is my understanding correct? Also, are you using any method as of now? Let me know so that I can help you accordingly.

Comment: yes that part is the tricky one. the other parameters i can handle, i can just send them via an ajax call to a method on my server, but the file, i have no idea how to send it to the server. the form basically should take the values in the form fields and mail them to a specific email, and the attachment is the most problematic, i have no idea how to inform the server to take it up.

Comment: Well, in that case you can try using jQuery file upload plugins such as [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demos) or [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload)